# Unsatisfied Dependecny

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies

Below are my files:

Recruiter.java

```
package com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Recruiter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="uuid")
    private String uuid;

    public Recruiter(int id, String name, String email, String uuid) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }


}
```

RecruiterContoller:

```
package com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.controller;

import com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.model.Recruiter;
import com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.service.RecruiterService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RecruiterController {
    @Autowired
    RecruiterService recruiterService;

    //The below function adds a recruiter to the company
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="recruiter/addRecruiter")
    public void addRecruiter(@RequestBody Recruiter recruiter){
        recruiterService.addRecruiter(recruiter);
    }
}
```

RecruiterRepo:

```
package com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.repository;

import com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.model.Recruiter;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RecruiterRepo extends JpaRepository<Recruiter, String> {
    
}
```

RecruiterService:

```
package com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.service;

import com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.model.Recruiter;
import com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.repository.RecruiterRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RecruiterService {

    @Autowired
    RecruiterRepo recruiterRepo;
    public void addRecruiter(Recruiter recruiter) {
        recruiterRepo.save(recruiter);
    }
}
```

RecruiterServiceApplication:

```
package com.jobapplication.recruiterservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication


public class RecruiterServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RecruiterServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I was trying to run the springboor application. SpringBoot application should have staretd.

I am getting :

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'recruiterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'recruiterService': Error creating bean with name 'recruiterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'recruiterRepo': Error creating bean with name 'recruiterRepo' defined in com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.repository.RecruiterRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.model.Recruiter

Answer (score 0):

The error from EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration says: **Not a managed type**: class com.jobapplication.recruiterservice.model.Recruiter

The reason for the error is that JPA needs a non argument constructor in each Entity class. Otherwise the JPARepository can't manage it.

**Solution**

Add the constructor with no arguments. Can be easy done with Lombok:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Recruiter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;
}
```

Comment: I did add a constructor with no arguments. 
`public Recruiter(){

} `
in the entity class.. I still get the same error